# calling User-control using while causing a lot of memory usage

Tags: c#, winforms

I have restaurant pos software developed using winform C#, after I finished the application and delivered it to a couple of my clients I noticed that after using the application for 30-60 min the application crash and stop responding. I tried to check what's the problem, I noticed that on the sales screen when I move between categories every time I go to a new category I get 10Mb of ram usage, the application start with 120Mb when I open the sales screen and reach to unlimited if I kept move between categories.

the code I'm using when the user clicks on categories:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// GET MATERIAL SECTION START
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="CategoryID"></param>
    private void Show_Food_UC(int CategoryID, int page_number)
    {
        try
        {
            flowLayoutPanel2.Controls.Clear();
            using (SqlDataReader reader = DBConn.ExecuteReader("get_materials_uc", CommandType.StoredProcedure,
            new SqlParameter[]
            {
                new SqlParameter("@page_num", page_number),
                new SqlParameter("@page_rows", PAGESIZE),
                new SqlParameter("@categid", CategoryID),
            }
            ))

            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    Food_uc UC = new Food_uc
                    {
                        Material_barcode = reader["barcode"].ToString(),
                        Material_Price = Convert.ToDecimal(reader["sell_price"].ToString()),
                        Material_name = reader["name"].ToString()
                    };
                    if (reader["image"] != DBNull.Value)
                    {
                        byte[] image = (byte[])reader["image"];
                        image = Decompress(image);
                        var stream = new MemoryStream();
                        stream.Write(image, 0, image.Length);
                        var bitmap = new Bitmap(stream);
                        UC.Material_image = bitmap;
                    }

                    UC.MaterialImage.Click += UC_PictureBox1_Click;
                    UC.Material_name_txt.Click += UC_PictureBox1_Click;
                    UC.MaterialImage.MouseDown += UC_PictureBox1_MouseDown;
                    UC.Material_name_txt.MouseDown += UC_PictureBox1_MouseDown;
                    UC.MaterialImage.MouseMove += UC_PictureBox1_MouseMove;
                    UC.Material_name_txt.MouseMove += UC_PictureBox1_MouseMove;
                    flowLayoutPanel2.Controls.Add(UC);
                }
            }
            ROWCOUNT = Convert.ToInt32(DBConn.ExecuteScaler("select count(categid) from materials where categid=@categid", CommandType.Text, new SqlParameter[] { new SqlParameter("@categid", CategoryID.ToString()) }));
            MAXPAGE = (int)Math.Ceiling(Convert.ToDecimal(ROWCOUNT / PAGESIZE));

            Barcode_txt.Select();

            if (PAGE_number == MAXPAGE)
            {
                Next_but.Enabled = false;
            }
            else
            {
                Next_but.Enabled = true;
            }

            if (PAGE_number == 0)
            {
                Back_but.Enabled = false;
            }
            else
            {
                Back_but.Enabled = true;
            }
        }
        catch (SqlException ex)
        {
            // Do some logging or something. 
            MessageBox.Show("There was an error accessing your data. DETAIL: " + ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

here are some images :
when I start the application :
[image]

when I start the sales screen:
[image]

after moving between categories:
[image]

Visual studio diagnostic tool :
[image]

is the ram usage is the reason why my application keeps crashing ??
what I'm doing wrong here ?? and how can I fix this problem?.

I'm using the `Decompress` method because I compress the images before storing them in the database and the `Decompress` method to decompress the images before showing them here is the method :

```
  /// <summary>
    /// decompress image
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="data"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static byte[] Decompress(byte[] data)
    {
        MemoryStream input = new MemoryStream(data);
        MemoryStream output = new MemoryStream();
        using (DeflateStream dstream = new DeflateStream(input, CompressionMode.Decompress))
        {
            dstream.CopyTo(output);
        }
        return output.ToArray();
    }
```

and here is my `Food_uc` User control code :

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Restaurants_POS.User_Controls
{
public partial class Food_uc : UserControl
{
    public Food_uc()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Material_name_txt.Parent = MaterialImage;
        Material_name_txt.Dock = DockStyle.Bottom;
        Material_name_txt.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(80, 0,0,0);
        Price_txt.Parent = MaterialImage;
        Price_txt.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(200, 108, 99, 255);
    }

    public string Material_name { get; set; }
    public decimal Material_Price { get; set; }
    public Image Material_image { get; set; }
    public string Material_barcode { get; set; }

    private void Food_uc_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Price_txt.Text = Material_Price.ToString("C1");
        Material_name_txt.Text  = Material_name;
        Material_name_txt.Tag = Material_barcode;
        MaterialImage.Tag = Material_barcode;
        if (Material_image != null)
        {
            MaterialImage.Image = Material_image;
        }
    }

    private void Price_txt_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Price_txt.Width = TextRenderer.MeasureText(Price_txt.Text, Price_txt.Font).Width;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Here's a few quick observations.  In general, you should create and dispose database connections as needed; that's how they are designed to work.  You have this code: `flowLayoutPanel2.Controls.Clear();`.  You really need to `Dispose` controls before you lose reference to them.  You create a `MemoryStream` and never clean it up

Comment: @Flydog57 for the database connection I have SQL helper and I'm using the USING() as I know using() dispose after finish is that not enough ??
For the `flowLayoutPanel2.Controls.Clear();` If I `Dispose ` the control will disappear from the form.

Comment: You cave to loop the child Controls of the FlowLayoutPanel and dispose of each of them: **do not make a `foreach` loop for this**, make a backwards `for` loop (`Clear()` doesn't dispose of anything). Then, your UCs must dispose of the Image objects you have set. What is `Decompress()` doing? Are you allocating other unmanaged resources there? In that context, also the `MemoryStream` should be declared with a `using` statement. But you won't need that either. Use the `ImageConverter` class, it will do that for you.

Comment: Playing games with controls on a WinForms page can cause issues.  Walk through the lifecycle of the controls on a simple default WinForms app and see what happens to them.  You need to be very careful that when you are about to no longer reference a control, you unwire all events/delegates and you dispose of things properly.  The best way to monitory memory usage in a .NET app is with Performance Monitor and the .NET memory counters.

Comment: @Jimi I'm using the `Decompress` method because I compress the images before storing them in the database and the `Decompress` method to decompress the images before showing them (the question is updated take a look), so your suggestion is to create a list to get the data and loop this list to create the UCs to show them in the `flowLayoutPanel` please help me with this thank you

Comment: @Flydog57 so what do you suggest to fix this ?? is there another way to get the data and show them in `UC` to show the materials ?? thank you.

Comment: Nope: `for (int i = flowLayoutPanel2.Controls.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--) { flowLayoutPanel2.Controls[i].Dispose(); }`. Also remove the event handlers you have added. This disposes of the child Controls. Then, your UCs, when disposed, need to call `Dispose()` on the unmanaged objects assigned (your Bitmaps and anything else you might have there). -- I don't see why you're compressing / decompressing Images that are already (usually) compressed, as the JPEG and PNG formats.

Comment: @Jimi Thank you, now it's way better the top memory usage is 150Mb now, and I'm setting my `MemoryStream` to `MemoryStream.SetLength(0);` and the `Bitmap` to `null`,
but I didn't get your point here "Also remove the event handlers you have added" do you mean these events: `UC.MaterialImage.Click += UC_PictureBox1_Click;` ,`UC.MaterialImage.MouseDown += UC_PictureBox1_MouseDown;`.. etc. if so how can I get the user input without them ??

Comment: Yes, those: remove in the same loop -- Setting the MemoryStream length to zero or a Bitmap to `null` does nothing. Desclare a MemoryStream with a `using` statement, so it's disposed implicitly and call `Dispose()` on the Bitmaps. -- A MemoryStream doesn't need to be disposed of if you directly use it as the Bitmap Stream in a constructor that accepts a Stream. It's handled *implicitly* by the GC. If you use it to Read / Write to a Byte array, and you do this often, better make sure it's disposed.

Comment: @Jimi excuse my many questions, I'm using the  `using` for the `MemoryStream ` but if I `Dispose()` the `Bitmaps` in the `sales screen` I'm getting an error on the `Food_uc `  `Parameter is not valid.` on this line of code `MaterialImage.Image = Material_image;`.
and the second question is how to remove the event handlers in this case I'll not be able to get the event when the user clicks on the user control` to get the material barcode.

Comment: Read again my previous comments: the Bitmaps are assigned to UserControls. When the UserControl is disposed - when you dispose the child Controls of your FlowLayoutPanel - the `Dispose()` method of the UCs is called. There, you dispose of the Bitmaps and any other unmanaged objects you have created in the meantime. Of course, you don't dispose of a Bitmap right after you have assigned it to an UC, otherwise, well, you cannot use it.

Comment: @Jimi Thank you very much for your time I'm grateful